# Mod Rewrite Create Fake Or Hide Wordpress Directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to fake or even hide my wordpress directory from 
mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php   to mysite.com/directory/page.php
or even mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php to mysite.com/fake1/fake2/fake3/page.php

Within my .htaccess file im using the following commands:

```
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/([^/]+)$ /fakedirectory$1 [L]
```

I;ve also tried

```
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/([^/]+)$ /fakedir1/fakedir2/fakedir3$1 [L]
```

But for some reason this is not working... Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the opposite.
Try this way (assuming your htaccess is in root folder)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule . /fakedirectory/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^fakedirectory/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What url are you trying to access ? Also, make sure it exists in `/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/`. For example, if you try `/fakedirectory/something/test/` it will be rewritten to `/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/something/test/`

Comment: @ Justin Iurman The URL im trying to access is mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php   ..  so page.php is in that full path ..

Comment: But you wanted to access it by `mysite.com/fakedirectory/page.php`, didn't you ?

Comment: Oh right, you also want it to be redirect when you access `/wp-content/...` ?

Comment: @ Justin Iurman   Yes, when a visitor visits mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php  they can see mysite.com/fakedirectory/page.php

Comment: I edited my answer. Right now, if a visitor go to `domain.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/something` it will be redirect to `domain.com/fakedirectory/something`

Comment: @ Justin Iurma , this works!! but for some reason i cant access certain directories within that path.. but im sure i can fix that.. thanks so much @ Justin Iurma!